# Different ways to print the exclamation mark symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I have some problems using the exclamation mark symbol explicitly, so I have to find another way to print it on math mode. I tried to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` but apparently I have to define a new macro and I really don't want to do that. Any advice would be great.

Edit: I have an application that generates a .tex file as output, the input is another file that I have to parse, and `!` is as reserved symbol, so I can't put it explicitly.

Comment: what is wrong with using `!` that is the normal way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Normally `$n!$` works fine

Comment: Thanks. I will add more information about the reason that I can't use the symbol explicitly.

Comment: `\newcommand*\bang{!}` then `$n\bang\bang$`.

Comment: Add `\DeclareMathSymbol{\bang}{\mathclose}{operators}{"21}` in the document preamble and use `\bang`

Comment: @Manuel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5Xl0Qry-hA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` is at position hex 21  so you can  use `^^21` which will make a `!` token just as if a `!` had been in the input.